# How can I make it so that here \\.(....|..) the points are only numbers [\\.(....|..)0-9]? (Java) Regex, matches?

Tags: java, regex

I have the regex `variable.matches("\.(....|..)")`. Now, my String needs to have a dot, and two or four characters after the dot. But my problem is, that I need that the characters are only numbers from 0-9. For example, I need that it only matches when I have for instance:

.12 or .22 or .8389 or.3920 and not .dd or .d93j, so the characters after the dot needs to be numbers, but `variable.matches("[\.(....|..)0-9]")` doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"\\.(\\d{2}|\\d{4})"
```

Comment: Okay thank you but how that work? What menas d{2} and d{4}?

Comment: @powqmnbvc21 they mean exactly 2 digits or exactly 4 digits

Comment: ah thank you :) Someone wrote me, that I need a $ sign like \\.(\\d{2}|\\d{4})$" its that true? He means that without a dolla sign I coud get problems

Comment: @powqmnbvc21 I recommend reading a tutorial on regular expressions, e.g. [this one over at `medium.com`](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) or [this one over at `regular-expressions.info`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: @powqmnbvc21 If it is at the end of line, `$` is needed.

Comment: Okay thank you, it works all. But I have a question. "\\.(\\d{2}|\\d{4})" Why we use two \, normally I thought that we use d with one \, with two it works, but why two?

Comment: @powqmnbvc21 we need two ``\`` since we use `String`s to represent regular expressions, and ``\`` is the standard escape character. Thus, to get a single ``\``, we need to write ``\\``.